# editing foleys - taking care of perspective and distance

Tags: foley-editing, perspective

apart from the whole sync aspect of foley editing i am just curious about:
how to treat individual foley clips in terms of distance and perspective (for the mixing) over time.
is it a good method to place the clips on tracks called FOL_foot1_dist, FOL_foot1_semidist and FOL_foot1_close according to their dist/perspective?

how did you take care of it when editing foleys?

thanks, 
pop

Answer (score 3):

What I find more flexible, especially with footsteps, is to have them on one track (if there's more than one person on-screen and they're at different distances or whatever, on separate tracks) and process things like volume and reverb (as a send effect) in time with the picture so that they sound like they're progressively getting closer or further away. This ultimately gives you more control over how things sound compared with using different clips depending on how close someone's feet are to camera.

Things like clothes tracks that don't typically produce loud reflections I'd just automate the volume.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for reply. i guess that when we do the spatial automation on one track it could be hard for the rerecording engineer to follow where we made the automations on the tracks, no?

Comment: I suppose so. The reason I tend to do things on fewer tracks is to save on CPU usage - I've had Pro Tools sessions crash on me before when the CPU usage was too high - and it cleans up the project a bit. You could always speak to your re-recording engineer about this.